# Quel est le sens de l'expression « bouzieu de bouzieu » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, jurons

Quel est le sens de l'expression « bouzieu de bouzieu » ?

Comment: Dans quel contexte l'as-tu rencontrée ? Je dirais que c'est une variante régionale de « Bon Dieu de bon Dieu », qui est une exclamation très générique, mais c'est difficile d'être sûr sans contexte.

Comment: Vous devriez présenter le contexte.

Comment: _Bouzieu de bouzieu_ je ne sais pas, mais **Bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu !** est apparemment un juron : http://www.amazon.fr/Myst%C3%A8res-donjon-Tome-proie-lombre/dp/2081237946 (merci google).

Answer (score 1):

Cette expression n'existe pas. Il est clair en [lisant le contexte](http://www.amazon.fr/Myst%C3%A8res-donjon-Tome-proie-lombre/dp/2081237946) que l'auteur du livre pour enfants en question cherche à recréer une langue moyenâgeuse (*malemort*) et populaire, en suggérant quelqu'un qui parle mal : *j'l'ai pas vu*,  *que'que* etc. C'est, comme le dit Gilles dans son commentaire, une variante de *bon dieu de bon dieu* non pas régionale (j'ai cherché si ça ne se dirait pas dans certains patois locaux mais le fait que je n'ai rien trouvé ne veut bien sûr pas dire que ça n'existe pas) mais très probablement pour coller au contexte de quelqu'un qui parle mal (et donc déforme les mots) et aussi comme [euphémisme](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/euph%C3%A9misme), car nommer dieu dans un juron n'est pas toujours bienvenu, ça pourrait choquer certains parents... et alors le livre se vendrait mal. Il existe de très nombreux mots pour remplacer dieu quand on ne veut pas le nommer : [parbleu](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/parbleu), [palsambleu](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/palsambleu) etc.  Mais *bouzieu* semble une création de l'auteur du livre en question.

Comment: C'est vrai, j'ai trouvé cette expression dans le livre «Mystères au Donjon» par Alain Surget. C'est un livre pour enfants. Un des personnages, le serviteur du donjon, s'exclame souvent de cette manière: «Bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu». Merci à tous pour vos réponses!

Comment: Ce n'est pas évident que ce soit une création je trouve, car on trouve beaucoup de références avec bouzieu, notamment un village inexistant nommé _Saint-Bouzieu-le-haut_ : https://www.google.fr/search?q=saint+bouzieu+le+haut

Comment: @Istao: Oui, Bouzieu est un nom de lieu (peut-être inexistant de nos jours mais qui a disparu - donc qui a existé) et aussi un nom de famille. Et il est fort probable que c'est pour ça (pour faire plus "naturel") que l'auteur a pris ce nom et pas autre chose. Il est clair dans le livre qu'il s'agit d'un juron.