# Quel est le sens du mot «traîne-charrette» ?

Tags: vocabulaire

Quel est le sens du mot «traîne-charrette» dans la phrase «Le traîne-charrette n'arrête pas de jurer.» ? Le mot se réfère certainement à une personne. Merci!

Comment: C'est celui qui traîne (tire) la charrette. Là aussi c'est une création de l'auteur, mais un francophone comprend vite, et ça penser à d'autres mots composés avec traîne (traîne-savates).

Comment: Un peu plus de contexte ne fait jamais de mal.

Comment: Alain Surget est un écrivain de littérature de jeunesse relativement connu, aussi professeur d'histoire, et tu trouveras certainement d'autres créations langagières dans le livre que tu es en train de lire.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez: C'est vrai que sur la forme tu n'as pas tort, mais-quand même, traîne-charrette c'est clair sans contexte, non ?

Answer (score 2):

Cette expression peu répertoriée est sans doute une déformation de la locution
« jurer comme un charretier ». Je crois que *traîne-charrette* est un néologisme argotique.

Answer (score 2):

Le terme correct est « charretier ». « *Traîne-charrette* » a été inventé par l'auteur pour donner une couleur locale à une scène se situant en 1429, comme le « *Bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu de bouzieu !* » qui le précède. Voir [Quel est le sens de l'expression « bouzieu de bouzieu » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8567/quel-est-le-sens-de-lexpression-bouzieu-de-bouzieu)